# What does $[f(x)](y)$ stand for in the formula $\{f: C(X, Y)\} \mapsto \{(x, y) \mapsto [f(x)](y)\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to study Fomenko's *Homotopical Topology*.

In Lecture 2.6, he gave a formula:

> Let $X, Y, Z$ be topological spaces. The formula $\{f: C(X, Y)\} \mapsto \{(x, y) \mapsto [f(x)](y)\}$ defines a map $C(X, C(Y, Z)) \rightarrow C(X \times Y, Z)$.

My question: What does $Z$ and $[f(x)](y)$ stand for in this expression? $f(x) \in Y$, but what does it mean to write $[f(x)](y)$ when both elements are members of $Y$ and multiplication isn't defined? Does it stand for any binary operation on $Y|_{\mathcal{Im} f} \times Y$ that is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is meant to denote an element of the domain $C(X,C(Y,Z))$, that means that $f(x)$ is not an element of $Y$ but rather an element of $C(Y,Z)$. In other words, $f(x)$ is a function that acts on $Y$, and thus $[f(x)](y)$ is the result, which is an element of $Z$.

(I have no idea what the symbols $\{f\colon C(X,Y)\}$ are supposed to indicate. But since the goal is to define a map $C(X,C(Y,Z))\to C(X\times Y,Z)$, it makes sense that $f$ should be an element of $C(X,C(Y,Z))$.)

For context, this idea of rethinking a function of two arguments as a family of functions of one argument is the same concept as [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).